# Sinatra is ignoring my layout.haml

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Starting a basic Sinatra app.  It doesn't seem to be using my layout template.  If I put garbage in my layout.haml, I get the Sinatra 500 error page about it not being a properly formed haml file. Running Ruby 1.9.2. on Windows with the gem of Sinatra, Haml, and Rack installed this evening.

**App Code:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

set :haml, :format => :html5

get '/' do
  "Hello world, it's #{Time.now} at the server!"
end
```

**App's Location / views / layout.haml**

```
%html
  %body
    = yield
```

**Source of Generated "http://localhost:4567/" Page**

```
Hello world, it's 2011-11-05 02:25:48 -0400 at the server!
```

^Notice the lack of my layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this purpose you have to say your template engine in action, something like this:

**app code:**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  haml :hello
end
```

**views/hello.haml:**

```
%p= "Hello world, it's #{Time.now} at the server!"
```

**views/layout.haml:**

```
%html
  %body
    = yield
```

Comment: I figured this same thing out a few minutes before you posted, but thanks anyways!
I had assumed that Sinatra would wrap my "quoted text" in the layout template, I guess that's not the case!